# Using TEL and EMAILTO at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css, tel

So im dealing with a minor issue on a website im coding, i made it so any image is clickable and will activate a phone number to call to as im dealing with bookings (restaurants, spa, services, when clicked it triggers the phone app on any mobile device and Skype on PC.

As not everyone has a Skype account (with credit), how could i implement the emailto tag when the website is used on a desktop on the same images that already have the tel tag?

Comment: as far as I know there's no reliable method to detect whether if it's a desktop or handheld device. The best thing you can do is depending on the screen width modify href tag of your link with js.

Comment: @SergeiKutanov Instead of modifying the `href` of the link with JS depending on the screen width, use a CSS media query to hide the email link and show the phone link when the window is small enough: `@media (max-width: 480px) { .email { display: none; } .phone { display: block; } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick solution using jQuery and [isMobile](https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile), along with a data attribute to hold the phone number.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Determine if we're using a mobile device
  if (isMobile.any) {

    // Loop through each link with the data-tel attribute
    $('[data-tel]').each(function() {

      $(this)
        // Update the link's href to use the telephone number
        .prop('href', 'tel:' + $(this).data('tel'))
        .text('Tel link (mobile detected)');
    });

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ismobilejs/0.4.1/isMobile.js"></script>

<a href="mailto:test@aol.com" data-tel="555-1234-567">
  Email link (desktop detected)
</a>
```

Comment: Im trying to use this one, thank you very much, i got one question, when i import it into my html it just creates a link in the corner of the page that says email detected. Should this  be able to replace every tel tag to emailto when a desktop is detected?